# How can use grounded primary coil transformer with BGJ/MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, transformer, bjt, pulse

So, I have a pulse signal transformer like this (freq is 1MHz):

[image]

In the secondary coil I want to get bipolar pulses. How can I make it using BJT or MOSFET switches and wich is better?
I know, that typically primary coil is in the collector of BJT, but how can i use it with grounded coil.
I need something like this, but I understand that in this case BJT won`t switch on properly.
[image]
Can I use pnp type like this??
[image]

Comment: What happens if you start with PNP or P-MOS transistors?

Comment: Could you check the circuit with p-n-p bjts, I`ve added it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems ok to me.
You can connect the collectors together and use one 5V source.

But more usual approach is to connect 5v to center tap and connect transistor low side (common emitter).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3zhVM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With mosfets it's also possible.

**Edit:**

The pnp version controlled with npn:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmkjY7.png)</sup>

Comment: A also thought about it, but I should deffinetely have this middle point grounded!

Comment: Using your proposal you will get 4.3v voltage across primary. In common emitter there will be full Vcc (5v).

Comment: 4.3v for wich circuit?

Comment: First one in your question (npn version). There will be drop if you don't put 5v7 to the base at least.

Comment: Actually I don`t think that this circuit will work. Because base current is limited by coil, or not?? What do you think about using p-n-p types (last picture in question)

Comment: It will work (npn version), this connection is called emitter follower, load (coil) is put into emitter circuit. But disadvantage is if you put 5v to the base you get 4v3 on coil only. So you must have base voltage higher (0.7v at least) than Vcc to turn it on fully.

Comment: I add a pnp version to my answer.